# Is there a way to see all Amazon reviews across its international sites?

Tags: amazon

Say a book has 10 reviews on amazon.com and 2 reviews each on amazon.co.uk, amazon.it and amazon.in, is there a way to aggregate all 16 reviews?

Comment: I removed the part of your question that could have made it a good candidate to be closed.

Comment: ohh. plugins are no-no here? thanks.

Comment: @otto: See [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a web app?](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/3705/354). In other words "I have this problem how can I resolve it?" is good. "I think a web app/plugin/service/widget will solve my problem. Where can I find a good one?" is bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Amazon Product Advertising API License Agreement prohibits use of the Reviews data for any purpose other than driving sales on the Amazon Site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18103934/325251). So I doubt if any site can lawfully provide the aggregated info. You may have to scrape & compile it yourself for your personal use by utilizing Amazon's consistent URL pattern for a product review page of each country.

Typically, the URL of a country-specific Amazon Reviews page for a product has this pattern:

```
http://www.amazon.{ccTLD}/product-reviews/{ASIN}/
```

For example, the reviews for the book with ASIN or product code of 0143031031 on Amazon.in are available at this URL: http://www.amazon.in/product-reviews/0143031031/